# Interpret the Parallelogram Law

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm starting to teach myself linear algebra from a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540780602) but I don't understand the following question.

*Interpret $||A+B||^2+||A-B||^2 = 2||A||^2 +2||B||^2$ as a "parallelogram law."*

Any suggestions on what it's looking for? I see on wikipedia the section about the [Parallelogram Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) but I'm not sure how to make this will apply. Can someone please help explain what this question is asking?

Comment: In the wiki page, the graph on the top right corner, the red lines are those 2 on the left hand side of your equation, and the blue lines are those 2 on the right hand side of your equation. Or the graph below it exactly explains your equation.